# Mocking User ClaimsPrincipal for Razor Pages Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an issue regarding writing a unit test for a Razor Page combined with MVVM. I want to test an `OnPostAsync()` method from Razor, however this method will call two more methods which require a `ClaimsPrincipal` User. I can't give the `User` as a parameter for these methods from within my test however.

My current test method:

```
[Test]
public void MakeBookingTest()
{            
    //Arrange
    var optionsbuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
    optionsbuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TeacherDB");
    var _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsbuilder.Options);

    JsonResult json = new JsonResult(true);
    _dbContext.ImportOption.Add(new ImportOption { Id = 1, isUnique = 1, Option = "Teacher" });
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    var mockedUserManager = GetMockUserManager();           

    var mockedCalendar = new Mock<ICalendarService>();

    Booking booking = new Booking {
        EventId = "2",
        ClassroomId = 3,
        BeginTime = DateTime.Now,
        EndTime = DateTime.Now,
        Description = "fjdkafjal",
        Summary = "Test01" };

    mockedCalendar.Setup(x => x.CreateEvent(booking, "2", "0863629@hr.nl", false)).Returns("111");

    var mockedRoleManager = GetMockRoleManager();

    var model = new MakeBookingModel(_dbContext, mockedUserManager.Object, mockedCalendar.Object, mockedRoleManager.Object);
    //var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

    var result = model.OnPostAsync();                        
}
```

The method which I want to test:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    CurrentRole = await _validation.GetCurrentRole(User);
    CurrentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

 //(rest of the code...)
```

`_validation.GetCurrentRole` method:

```
public async Task<string> GetCurrentRole(ClaimsPrincipal User)
{
    ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);            
    Task<IList<string>> rolesUser = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);
    return rolesUser.Result.First();
}
```

I can't seem to make `User` in the `OnPostAsync`/`GetCurrentRole` to not be *null*.

How would I assign `User` to those methods?

Comment: Is the `User` property on the `MakeBookingModel`  readonly?

Comment: It's inherited from PageModel, and seems to be public

Comment: This should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: You will need to set the user through a mocked http context which is part of the PageContext.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you for thequick replies, I'm taking a look at it right now. I've tried to mock a httpcontext before and it didn't seem to work, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: Provided an example that uses the `DefaultHttpContext` so that you do not need to mock it.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, it's not an unit test. A unit test by definition tests a unit of code, usually not more than a single method. You have to big/high dependencies on infrastucture, making that an integration test (in unit tests you don't use in memory database, you'd mock an repository or something like that). Also we have no idea what `MakeBookingModel` is. A service? Model class? from the method and anti forgering token it looks more like a controller, making it even more of an integration test. For it use `TestServer` class. So its absolutely not clear what you try to achieve

Comment: In order to be able to perform unit tests a strict **REQUIREMENT** is to correctly separate concerns (such as SRP from SOLID principle), clearly splitting the responsibilities and consequently use interfaces and dependency injection. This makes unit tests easier. And for everything else, well as said: there's `TestServer` class to test requests, and which can be used with a preconfigured classes and DI/IoC container

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `User` via the HTTP context which is part of the `PageModel`'s `PageContext`

```
// Arrange

//...code removed for brevity

//Create test user
var displayName = "User name";
var identity = new GenericIdentity(displayName);
var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
// use default context with user
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() {
    User = principle
}
//need these as well for the page context
var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
// need page context for the page model
var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext) {
    ViewData = viewData
};
//create model with necessary dependencies
var model = new MakeBookingModel(_dbContext, mockedUserManager.Object, mockedCalendar.Object, mockedRoleManager.Object) {
    PageContext = pageContext
};

//Act

//...
```

Reference [Razor Pages unit tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

You are mixing async and blocking calls like `.Result` which is causing a deadlock in `GetCurrentRole`.

Refactor to be async all the way through

```
public async Task<string> GetCurrentRole(ClaimsPrincipal User) {
    ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);            
    var rolesUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);
    return rolesUser.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you so much! The only problem I have now is that the test itself doesn't go into the second method (the CurrentRole = ...GetUserAsync(), but just seems to stop after the first part. But this will help a great deal.

Comment: @RaspberryInIT you had a deadlock. check update in answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this! I had been struggling to unit test my Razor page because it didnt pass in a context to the model and i still needed to access User.Identity.Name and it was so frustrating and i hate it takes soooo many lines of code but it fixed the problem so thank u!