# Unit Testing Razor Pages that inherit from a BasePageModel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages app where several services are used by all pages in the site and have added those services to a `BasePageModel`, that I inherit from on each Razor Page. My `BasePageModel` looks something like this:

```
public abstract class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
    private IUserClaimsService _userClaims;
    private IAuthorizationService _authService;

    protected virtual IUserClaimsService UserClaimsService => _userClaims ?? (_userClaims = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserClaimsService>());
    protected virtual IAuthorizationService AuthService => _authService ?? (_authService = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthorizationService>()); 
}
```

The Razor Page itself would look something like this:

```
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        var HasAccess = (await AuthService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PermissionName")).Succeeded;
        if (!HasAccess)
        {
            return new ForbidResult();
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I am creating unit tests to test authorization on my Razor Pages. My authorization has policies that depend on user claims. What I'd like to do is to mock the user claims and test whether authorization succeeds or fails accordingly, depending on the page. However, I am not able to get to the `UserClaimsService` to mock it from my test. I instantiate the pageModel but am unable to get to any of the `BasePageModel` values (e.g. `UserClaimsService`). Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Comment: As an aside, the service locator anti pattern used via the request services should be avoided. Follow Explicit Dependency Principle via constructor injection.

Comment: [Razor Pages unit tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1) should also prove useful to you.

Comment: Found this as well [Mocking User ClaimsPrincipal for Razor Pages Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896025/5233410)

Comment: @Nkosi: I am aware of these methodologies, but since the constructor is in the BasePageModel, not the current page under test's model. I am wanting to be able to get to that base constructor but have been unable.

Comment: You have no constructor in the base model for the derived class to call. You have two fields and two properties, but no base constructor

Comment: Doh! You are right. I will try to refactor. Thanks!

Comment: You also appear to be mixing cross cutting concerns where it comes to the user claims and authorization but i guess that is outside of the scope of what is currently being asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The service locator anti pattern used via the request services should be avoided. Follow [Explicit Dependency Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) via constructor injection.

```
public abstract class BasePageModel : PageModel {
    protected readonly IAuthorizationService authService;

    protected BasePageModel(IAuthorizationService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }
    
    protected async Task<bool> HasAccess(string permissionName) {
        return (await authService.AuthorizeAsync(User, permissionName)).Succeeded;
    }
}
```

The Razor page itself would then become

```
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel {
    public IndexModel(IAuthorizationService authService) : base (authService) {
        //...
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet() {
        if (!HasAccess("PermissionName")) {
            return new ForbidResult();
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

For testing now the explicit dependencies can be mocked as needed for isolated unit tests

```
public async Task Index_Should_Be_Forbidden() {
    // Arrange
    var authService = Mock.Of<IAuthorizationService>(_ =>
        _.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), null, It.IsAny<string>()) == 
            Task.FromResult(AuthorizationResult.Failed())
    );

    //Create test user with what ever claims you want
    var displayName = "UnAuthorized User name";
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(displayName);
    var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    // use default context with user
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() {
        User = principle
    }
    //need these as well for the page context
    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
    // need page context for the page model
    var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext) {
        ViewData = viewData
    };
    //create model with necessary dependencies
    var model = new IndexModel(authService) {
        PageContext = pageContext //context includes User 
    };

    //Act
    var result = await model.OnGet();
    
    //Assert
    result.Should()
        .NotBeNull()
        .And.BeOfType<ForbidResult>();
}
```

Reference [Razor Pages unit tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

You also appear to be mixing cross cutting concerns where it comes to the user claims and authorization but I guess that is outside of the scope of what is currently being asked.

Reference [Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In our architecture, authentication is indeed (and is handled as) a cross-cutting concern, but per-page authorization is complex enough that it cannot be handled as a cross-cutting concern. In addition to allowing/disallowing access to pages based on authorization rules that vary depending on the page we're on, we are also using authorization to show/hide buttons and fields.

Comment: Nkosi: I'm getting a syntax error on the setup of the authService: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<AuthorizationResult>' and 'AuthorizationResult'". I've tried various fixes but am unable to make it work. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @LaurieDickinson typo on my part as I wrote it free hand in notepad. Fixed.